# Combining two maps on same key in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm pretty new to Elixir and just wanted to find what the best way is to combine two maps with on same key. To be more specific:

```
name_map = %{
  105 => "Jim",
  48 => "Maria",
  62 => "Karen",
  888 => "Foo"
}

job_map = %{
  105 => "Social worker",
  48 => "Programmer",
  62 => "Teacher",
  999 => "Bar"
}
```

and I am trying to get

```
combined_map = %{
  105 => %{"name" => "Jim", "job" => "Social worker"},
  48 => %{"name" => "Maria", "job" => "Programmer"},
  62 => %{"name" => "Karen", "job" => "Teacher"},
  888 => %{job: nil, name: "Foo"},
  999 => %{job: "Bar", name: nil}}
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you want to do if a key is only present in one map?

Comment: Putting a nil in is fine, good catch!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A straightforward solution: get all the keys from the two maps, iterate over the keys, and retrieve values from the maps and construct the tuple `{key, %{name: name, job: job}}`, then reduce the tuples into a map.

```
name_map = %{
  105 => "Jim",
  48 => "Maria",
  62 => "Karen",
  888 => "Foo"
}

job_map = %{
  105 => "Social worker",
  48 => "Programmer",
  62 => "Teacher",
  999 => "Bar"
}

combined_map = Map.keys(name_map) ++ Map.keys(job_map)
               |> Stream.uniq
               |> Stream.map(&{&1, %{name: name_map[&1], job: job_map[&1]}})
               |> Enum.into(%{})

%{48 => %{job: "Programmer", name: "Maria"},
  62 => %{job: "Teacher", name: "Karen"},
  105 => %{job: "Social worker", name: "Jim"}, 
  888 => %{job: nil, name: "Foo"},
  999 => %{job: "Bar", name: nil}}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but could you explain why you used Stream instead of Enum (or is it just preference)?

Comment: Because `Enum.uniq` and `Enum.map` will create intermediate lists, but the counterpart of `Stream` won't.

Comment: Good to know! :)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you have same keys in both maps, it’s fairly easy:

```
Map.merge(name_map, job_map, fn _k, v1, v2 ->
  %{name: v1, job: v2}
end)
#⇒ %{48 => %{job: "Programmer", name: "Maria"},
#    62 => %{job: "Teacher", name: "Karen"},
#   105 => %{job: "Social worker", name: "Jim"}}
```

Whether you want to support names without jobs and vice versa:

```
Enum.into(Map.keys(name_map) ++ Map.keys(job_map), %{}, fn k ->
  {k, %{name: Map.get(name_map, k), job: Map.get(job_map, k)}}
end)
#⇒ %{48 => %{job: "Programmer", name: "Maria"},
#    62 => %{job: "Teacher", name: "Karen"},
#   105 => %{job: "Social worker", name: "Jim"},
#   888 => %{job: nil, name: "Foo"},
#   999 => %{job: "Bar", name: nil}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Transform each map to have the values underneath the `job` or `name` key, then `Map.merge` to combine entries.

```
name_map = %{
  105 => "Jim",
  48 => "Maria",
  62 => "Karen",
}

job_map = %{
  105 => "Social worker",
  48 => "Programmer",
  62 => "Teacher"
}

Map.merge(
  Enum.into(name_map, %{}, fn {k, v} -> {k, %{name: v}} end), 
  Enum.into(job_map, %{}, fn {k, v} -> {k, %{job: v}} end), 
  fn _k, v1, v2 -> Map.merge(v1, v2) end)

%{48 => %{job: "Programmer", name: "Maria"},
  62 => %{job: "Teacher", name: "Karen"},
  105 => %{job: "Social worker", name: "Jim"}}
```